# What are the main differences between ancient and modern scepticism?

Tags: history-of-philosophy, skepticism, pascal

What would the main differences be between 'ancient' and 'modern' scepticism?
Specifically, how could one contrast the writings of Sextus Empiricus vs Pascal & Montaigne?
Any insight would be greatly appreciated.